# can I have resize effect with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I find a webgis website http://wwgis.net/maptestdemo.html
openlayers can help me have such effect? then how?

I have tryied 'resize', which seems not so good as above?

Comment: OpenLayers seems to only have the `resize` `transitionEffect` at the moment. Your example uses *Flash*, but OpenLayers is bound by what the browsers are capable of. I don't know, but maybe HTML5 in the future will allow for more spectacular visual navigational effects :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve resize effect by adding `transitionEffect: 'resize'` to a layer. Code can look like this:

```
var tiled_resize_effect = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
  "WMS tiled resize", 
  "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?",
  {layers: 'basic'}, 
  {transitionEffect: 'resize'}
);
```

And [here's the demo](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/transition.html) that shows how it works:

I guess it's hard to achieve same smooth transition effect as in example that you reference to because it uses Flash.

Comment: Yes, I have tried `transitionEffect: 'resize' `, anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same in OpenLayers 3